# Very high TTFB on shared hosting

Tags: php, mysql, apache, shared-hosting

I have a php, Mysql, Apache site. Which performance really fast in the order of 20ms to 40ms for page loads when tested locally.

However, when i hosted this on a Shared hosting server and configured all configurations and settings as close to the local host as possible, I am seeing a relatively slow website.

The Network latency is just about 3ms as the shared host server is located in the same city and a normal ping to the ipaddress proves it is 3ms.

The site takes aanywhere between 150ms to 4seconds to load. 
90% of the time its around 400ms. And rarely it does take 2 seconds and upto 4 seconds to load the page.

Upon checking the timeline. I am seeing a very high TTFB. a minimum of 150ms and sometimes even 1.6 seconds. I also noticed, whenever this happens the ttfb of all resources such as font.woff files etccf are very high too.

What could be possible reasons here.  Does it sound like a poor performance on shared hosting server and should i go for a cloud based server ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is pretty simple. Localhost will very well have low latencies because is simply "local".

You will not get the same kind of performance on shared hosting servers because you are not providing the same kind of latency for every user. e.g If your client accesses from Asia and your hosting happens in the US, you are bound to get high latencies. But on the contrary, if you serve an Asian client from a hosting in Asia and the US client from a hosting in the US, you'll get much better response times.

Another possibility is to serve static assets via CDN. CDN would geo-replicate your assets and manage the serving the client from the closest replicated asset.

Another reason could be your data access patterns. If your webserver is accessing a database service which is not in the vicinity of your application (by vicinity I mean the same local network) and has to go via the public DNS route, that will definitely cause very very high latencies and is a bad architectural pattern in general.

Cloud based servers provide you with two main benefits to this regard:

1. You get a very low-latency local network where you can spawn machines and get around 10Gbps connections on the network (internal latencies are improved drastically!).
2. You get geo-replication (beware! Not out of the box, you need to design your architecture which can scale and then use the CDN and geo-replication services provided by your cloud provider)